# How to delete words from a dataframe column that are present in dictionary in Pandas

Tags: python-2.7, pandas, dataframe

An extension to  : 
[Removing list of words from a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25346058/removing-list-of-words-from-a-string)

I have following dataframe and I want to delete frequently occuring words from df.name column:

df :

```
name
Bill Hayden
Rock Clinton
Bill Gates
Vishal James
James Cameroon
Micky James
Michael Clark
Tony Waugh  
Tom Clark
Tom Bill
Avinash Clinton
Shreyas Clinton
Ramesh Clinton
Adam Clark
```

I'm creating a new dataframe with words and their frequency with following code :

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data.name.str.split(expand=True).stack().value_counts())
df.reset_index(level=0, inplace=True)
df.columns = ['word', 'freq']
df = df[df['freq'] >= 3]
```

which will result in

df2 :

```
word    freq
Clinton 4
Bill    3
James   3
Clark   3
```

Then I'm converting it into a dictionary with following code snippet :

```
    d = dict(zip(df['word'], df['freq']))
```

Now if I've to remove words from df.name that are in d(which is dictionary, with word : freq), I'm using following code snippet :

```
def check_thresh_word(merc,d):
    m = merc.split(' ')
    for i in range(len(m)):
            if m[i] in d.keys():
                return False
    else:
        return True

def rm_freq_occurences(merc,d):
    if check_thresh_word(merc,d) == False:
        nwords = merc.split(' ')
        rwords = [word for word in nwords if word not in d.keys()]
        m = ' '.join(rwords)
    else:
        m=merc
    return m

df['new_name'] = df['name'].apply(lambda x: rm_freq_occurences(x,d))
```

But in actual my dataframe(df) contains nearly 240k rows and i've to use threshold(thresh=3 in above sample) greater than 100.
So above code takes lots of time to run because of complex search.
Is there any effiecient way to make it faster??

Following is a desired output :

```
name
Hayden
Rock
Gates
Vishal
Cameroon
Micky
Michael
Tony Waugh
Tom
Tommy
Avinash
Shreyas
Ramesh
Adam
```

Thanks in advance!!!!!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`replace`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.replace.html) by regex created by joined all values of column `word`, last [`strip`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.strip.html) traling whitespaces:

```
data.name = data.name.replace('|'.join(df['word']), '', regex=True).str.strip()
```

Another solution is add `\s*` for select zero or more whitespaces:

```
pat = '|'.join(['\s*{}\s*'.format(x) for x in df['word']])
print (pat)
\s*Clinton\s*|\s*James\s*|\s*Bill\s*|\s*Clark\s*

data.name = data.name.replace(pat, '', regex=True)
```

---

```
print (data)
          name
0       Hayden
1         Rock
2        Gates
3       Vishal
4     Cameroon
5        Micky
6      Michael
7   Tony Waugh
8          Tom
9          Tom
10     Avinash
11     Shreyas
12      Ramesh
13        Adam
```

Comment: Solution looks great!!! But the name column contains some unicode data which is encoded in utf-8... So it's giving error as 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xe9' in position 3: ordinal not in range(128)

Comment: UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xe9' in position 3: ordinal not in range(128)

Comment: Can you try `'|'.join(x.decode('utf-8') for x in df['word'])` ?

Comment: data.factual_name.replace(u'|'.join(df['word']).encode('utf-8').strip(), '', regex=True).str.strip()

Comment: If I use this it gives nothing to repeat

Comment: sorry, need `print(u'|'.join(df['word'].str.encode('utf-8')))`

Comment: print(u'|'.join(df['word']).encode('utf-8')) this prints | separated  words

Comment: but if i add .str.encode('utf-8'))) to it it gives 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xe9' in position

Comment: but if i add it in replace it gives nothing to repeat

Comment: hmmm, data are confidental?

Comment: hmmm, so  it seems need conver columns to unicode and then it working nice

Comment: else can you suggest any enhancement in my existing method?? using dictionary

Comment: Can you use something like this in name column Ãvinash ©linton and run again??

Comment: OK, it seems there are some problems in data, Can you anonymize first 10 values with problematic data (or add problematic data), convert column to pickle and send it my my email in my profile? `data.name.head(10).to_pickle('pkl.pkl')` ?

Comment: Sorry, withour pickle is hard help you :(

Comment: Or is not possible send me csv file? Because data dependent problem.

Comment: It's confidential.. So I can't send csv/pkl files through mails

Comment: I know it, so please change only first 5 rows to some data with no sense like `aaýáčší` to `cafâ”œÃ¢â”¬âŒ ` and then sent it ;) I need only your unicode data, not confidental.

Comment: and better is pickle, because to_csv can change data format, to_pickle not.

Comment: OK, please dont forget add some problematic values ;) Also do you use python 2, right?