# how to specify to use pandas .replace() instead of str.replace() when defining a function?

Tags: python, regex, pandas

I want to filter out certain words from a pandas dataframe column and make a new column of the filtered text. I attempted the solution from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48684774/how-to-delete-words-from-a-dataframe-column-that-are-present-in-dictionary-in-pa), but I think im having the issue of python thinking that I want to call the `str.replace()` instead of `df.replace()`. I'm not sure how to specify the latter as long as I'm calling it within a function.

**df:**

```
id     old_text 
0      my favorite color is blue
1      you have a dog
2      we built the house ourselves
3      i will visit you
```

```
def removeWords(txt):
     words = ['i', 'my', 'myself', 'we', 'our', 'ours', 'ourselves', 'you', 'your', 'yours', 'yourself']
     txt = txt.replace('|'.join(words), '', regex=True)
     return txt

df['new_text'] = df['old_text'].apply(removeWords)
```

**error:**

```
TypeError: replace() takes no keyword arguments
```

**desired output:**

```
id     old_text                         new_text
0      my favorite color is blue        favorite color is blue
1      you have a dog                   have a dog
2      we built the house ourselves     built the house 
3      i will visit you                 will visit you
```

**other things tried:**

```
def removeWords(txt):
     words = ['i', 'my', 'myself', 'we', 'our', 'ours', 'ourselves', 'you', 'your', 'yours', 'yourself']
     txt = [word for word in txt.split() if word not in words]
     return txt

df['new_text'] = df['old_text'].apply(removeWords)
```

**this returns:**

```
id     old_text                         new_text
0      my favorite color is blue        favorite, color, is, blue
1      you have a dog                   have, a, dog
2      we built the house ourselves     built, the, house 
3      i will visit you                 will, visit, you
```

Comment: Instead of using a function and `apply`, just use the built in method [series.str.replace](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.replace.html) as in `df['new_text'] = df['old_text'].str.replace(args)`

Comment: I certainly could. However I'm trying to follow a convention and I'd like to understand this issue better

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From this line:

```
txt.replace(rf"\b({'|'.join(words)})\b", '', regex=True)
```

This is the signature for `pd.Series.replace` so your function takes a series as input. On the other hand,

```
df['old_text'].apply(removeWords)
```

applies the function to *each cell* of `df['old_text']`. That means, `txt` would be just a string, and the signature for `str.replace` does not have keyword arguments (`regex=True`) in this case.

TLDR, you want to do:

```
df['new_text'] = removeWords(df['old_text'])
```

Output:

```
   id                      old_text                new_text
0   0     my favorite color is blue    favorte color s blue
1   1                you have a dog              have a dog
2   2  we built the house ourselves   bult the house selves
3   3              i will visit you                wll vst
```

But as you can see, your function replaces the `i` within the words. You may want to modify the pattern so as it only replaces the whole words with the boundary indicator `\b`:

```
def removeWords(txt):
    words = ['i', 'my', 'myself', 'we', 'our', 'ours', 'ourselves', 'you', 'your', 'yours', 'yourself']
    
    # note the `\b` here
    return txt.replace(rf"\b({'|'.join(words)})\b", '', regex=True)
```

Output:

```
   id                      old_text                 new_text
0   0     my favorite color is blue   favorite color is blue
1   1                you have a dog               have a dog
2   2  we built the house ourselves         built the house 
3   3              i will visit you              will visit
```