# Removing Word but not Subword from a Sentence in Python

Tags: python, string, machine-learning, nlp, recurrent-neural-network

I need to remove a given vector of words from a sentence (a given String) in Python.

The problem is that i want to remove exactly words but not substrings or subwords.

note: i cannot assume that before or after the word there is a space

I tried the `.replace(word,"")` function but not works

example: `s = "I'am at home and i will work by webcam call"`

when i do `s.replace("am","")`

outputs: `i' at home and i will work by webc call`

maybe can help the tokenization?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Removing list of words from a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25346058/removing-list-of-words-from-a-string)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a list comprehension like so:

```
sentence_filtered = " ".join([word for word in sentence.split() if word.lower() not in vector_of_words])
```

Comment: "note: i cannot assume that before or after the word there is a space"

Comment: Before OR after. I assumed that meant the starting (no space before) or ending (no space after) words. Can OP please clarify.

Comment: How does that make a difference? Point is, that `split` won't split `am` from `i'am` and thus it will not work on the provided example.

Comment: "i want to remove exactly words but not substrings or subwords." `am` is a substring of `i'am`. Would be more helpful if the OP supplied 'expected results'.

Comment: The `i'am` might be a bad example, as you could argue whether that's one word or two, but I think it's pretty clear that OP also wants to remove words if they are e.g. followed by punctuation, like commas or quotes.

Answer (score 3):

You can use a regular expression to [`re.sub`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.sub) with a word boundary `\b` character:

```
>>> import re
>>> s = "I'am at home and i will work by webcam call"
>>> re.sub(r"\bam\b", "", s)
"I' at home and i will work by webcam call"
```

With a list of words, you can use a loop, or build a disjunction from the several words using `|`, e.g. `"am|and|i"`. Optionally use the `re.I` flag to ignore upper/lowercase:

```
>>> words = ["am", "and", "i"]
>>> re.sub(r"\b(%s)\b" % "|".join(words), "", s, flags=re.I)
"' at home   will work by webcam call"
```

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48051693/4755520) to the question mentioned above gives the exact and straightforward solution for the OP's problem that essentially boils down to `re.split('\W+', "Don't answer duplicates, please")`.

Comment: @ayorgo Not really. I scanned the answers on the "dupe", but none really did what OP wanted. E.g. the one you linked to (which indeed does something similar to `\b` with `\W`) will discard any punctuation.

Comment: Tbh it's not completely clear what the OP needs exactly but given the tags [tag:machine-learning], [tag:nlp] and [tag:recurrent-neural-network] it seems that having a list of words for an output would suffice.