# Remove the bad words from a text using Python

Tags: python

I have a list of bad words and another list of sentences. I want to list all the sentences that have at least one bad word in `newlines` list then I want to delete it so I have pure sentences and I try like this but not work

```
f = open("demofile.txt")
read1= f.readlines()
g = open("abuse dic.txt")
read2 = g.readlines()
newlines = []
for line in f:
    if any(s in line for s in read2):
        newlines.append(line)
print(newlines)
g.close()
f.close()
```

Comment: What does "not work" mean? Are you getting errors? Does `newlines` remain empty? What's the issue?

Comment: the issue in the result , dosent append any sentence in newlines[]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code

```
if any(s in line for s in read2):
    newlines.append(line)
```

simply appends the line as is. You need to repeatedly remove all bad words from `line` before you append it to `newlines`. This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25346119) shows a good way to do so.